# Gremlin Traversal in Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j, traversal, gremlin

In my database, I can extract subgraphs by using a native Neo4J traversal that looks a little like this:

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.description()
.depthFirst()
.relationships(Relation.REL1, Direction.OUTGOING)
.relationships(Relation.REL2, Direction.OUTGOING);
```

And it works like a charm. Now I would like to do one of two things, but I'm expecting the latter to be a little easier.

1. I would like to store the traversal in a Tinkerpop blueprints graph object.
2. I would like to execute the same query in Gremlin (via the java api) and store that in the same type of graph object.

When I say store the traversal as a graph object, what I actually mean is that I want every single node that I passed by during that traversal (so not only the leaf nodes) to be stored in such a graph object and then I want every relation of which both start and endnode exist in the new graph object to be created. That includes relations that I did not include in my traversal description.

Comment: What do you mean by storing? This is just traversing without modifying anything?

Comment: I want to extract a subgraph from the database. To find out which nodes are in the subgraph, I perform a traversal. I've made the rules for my traversal so that every endnode is part of the subgraph. This subgraph needs to be stored in a Tinkerpop Blueprints graph object, hence why I think it would be easier to execute a similar query in Gremlin.

Comment: I've already managed to do this by storing the node id's that I catch in the traversal in a list, then copying the entire Neo4Jgraph in a Tinkergraph and removing all the nodes that are not on the list. But that's as inefficient as it gets. I don't want to copy the entire graph and delete what I don't need, I only want to insert into the Tinkergraph the nodes that I found with the traversal, and every relation that exists between those nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like `g.outE.filter{it.label == "REL1" || it.label == "REL2"}.inV.loop(3)` or so?

Comment: How would I convert this to use the Java API? I already tried with ScriptEngine and it didn't work and tbh the Loop function for a GremlinPipeline sort of puzzles me.

Comment: What do you mean by Java API? You mean `blueprints` or running groovy/gremlin in Java?

Comment: Gremlin has a Java API so that you don't need to learn a new language: http://www.tinkerpop.com/maven2/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/gremlin-java/1.5/api/index.html?com/tinkerpop/gremlin/java/GremlinPipeline.html